# Passing PK class with composite primary key to REST resources

Tags: java, rest, key, composite

I'm developing a Java Web project, that it use NetBeans's automatic mechanism to create RESTful web services from entity classes (NetBeans 7.2, server GlassFish 3.1.2). When I'm creating entity class which has composite primary key, two classes are created: `EntityClass` and `EntityClassPK`, annotated with `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`. I try use it from `GET` and `REMOVE REST` resources.

The application is deployed OK, but when I try the operation `"Test RESTful Web Services"` in NetBeans, the WADL can't open and attach this server.log:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes: SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST.remove(entity.ColocacionesbyMadPK) at parameter at index 0 
SEVERE: Method, public void service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST.remove(entity.ColocacionesbyMadPK), annotated with DELETE of resource, class service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method. 
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public entity.ColocacionesbyMad service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST.find(entity.ColocacionesbyMadPK) at parameter at index 0 
SEVERE: Method, public entity.ColocacionesbyMad service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST.find(entity.ColocacionesbyMadPK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.ColocacionesbyMadFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

Any idea?? Thanks!!